# convert non-ANSI join operators

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I've just upgraded my SQL Server database from 2000 to 2005 with compatibility mode 90, and I now find I have some queries using non-ANSI join operators, which are not fully supported in SQL Server 2005. So I need to convert the following code to ANSI-compliant form.

```
FROM gaf (nolock),
     gaf_dress as D (nolock index = pkgaf_DRESS_GUM),
     gaf_dress as M (nolock index = pkgaf_DRESS_GUM),
     mobile (nolock index = pkmobileID),
     Quest (nolock index = pkQuestID)

WHERE
gaf.ID = mobile.ID
and gaf.DRESS_GUM_1 *= D.DRESS_GUM
and gaf.DRESS_GUM_2 *= M.DRESS_GUM
and gaf.ID *= Quest.ID
and gaf.RECORD=1
and na2.PURPOSE <> 'Doore'
and gaf.PD_THRU > dateadd(dd, -1, dateadd(mm, -13, convert(datetime, convert(varchar(6), 
getdate(), 112) + '01')))
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I tried this one before

```
FROM Name (nolock)inner join mobile
on Name.ID = Demographics.ID left outer join NA1
on Name.ADDRESS_NUM_1 = NA1.ADDRESS_NUM left outer join NA2
on Name.ADDRESS_NUM_2 = NA2.ADDRESS_NUM left outer join ACSW
on Name.ID = ACSW.ID 
;with Name_Address (nolock,(index(pkName_AddressADDRESS_NUM)))as NA1
;with Name_Address (nolock, (index(pkName_AddressADDRESS_NUM))as NA2 ;with mobile(nolock, 
(index (pkmobileID))
;with ACSW (nolock, (index (pkACSWID)))
WHERE gaf.MEMBER_RECORD=1
and na2.PURPOSE <> 'MAIN'
and gaf.PAID_THRU > dateadd(dd, -1, dateadd(mm, -13, convert(datetime, 
convert(varchar(6),  getdate(), 112) + '01')))
```

But it’s throw me this error “Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 302
Incorrect syntax near '('.”

Comment: '*=' means left outer join, if I recall correctly.

Comment: It’s definitely works in SQL 2k but not on SQL 2k5

Comment: I tried this one before but it’s throw me this error “Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 302
Incorrect syntax near '('.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FROM gaf
 INNER JOIN mobile ON gaf.ID = mobile.ID
 LEFT JOIN gaf_dress as D ON and gaf.DRESS_GUM_1 = D.DRESS_GUM 
 LEFT JOIN gaf_dress as M ON gaf.DRESS_GUM_2 = M.DRESS_GUM AND M.PURPOSE <> 'Doore'
 LEFT JOIN Quest ON gaf.ID = Quest.ID

WHERE gaf.RECORD=1
  AND gaf.PD_THRU > dateadd(dd, -1, dateadd(mm, -13, convert(datetime, convert(varchar(6), 
getdate(), 112) + '01')))
```

Comment: WOW sorry na2 stands for M

Comment: WHERE
gaf.ID = mobile.ID---is that should be converted as inner join?

Comment: Yes, = to INNER, *= to LEFT, =* to RIGHT - and if na2 is M then that's also moved to JOIN condition

Comment: @user2524982 I have now, but I have no idea what are you trying with that query :) Why don't you post your whole query starting from the top (`FROM` can't be on top) and explain your expected results? One thing for sure - that is not how CTE (With) is used.